# Template resolution and height don't work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with height when I change the resolution or change a monitor with lowest resolution.

My code:

```
html, body, footer {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
```

Comment: getbootstrap.com uses grids that will respond to the viewport automatically.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Sure i want to fix height.

Comment: What happens when you use the code and what do you expect to happen? "Does not work" is not detailed enough. You could edit your question and include some screenshots, so we know what you actually mean.

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The default browser style for `body` makes it have an `8px` margin. Set `body { margin: 0; }`

Also put `position: relative` on `html` and `body`

Comment: I do then but no effets

Comment: Werks 4 mE. What brousR RU yoosing?